# How can I get the last day of the month in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I find the last day of the month in C#?

Comment: DateTime.DaysInMonth(1980, 08);

Please see this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-a-month

Answer (score 399, accepted):

Another way of doing it:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, 
                                   today.Month, 
                                   DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, 
                                                        today.Month));
```

Comment: I was about to suggest System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth.GetDaysInMonth but this was way shorter.

Comment: Way late, but to any traveler. It may be important to specify the kind if you intend on making this more generic or an extension method in your app.  `DateTime.SpecifyKind( new DateTime(/*...*/) , existingDateTime.Kind)` otherwise you risk losing the existing date time's timezone infomration.

Answer (score 76):

Something like:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Which is to say that you get the first day of next month, then subtract a day. The framework code will handle month length, leap years and such things.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to write, but thought someone would beat me to it :) +1

Comment: Humm .. if it is repeatedly used at many places in your code, write this as an Extension method on dateTime class which you can invoke on DateTime.Now. For ex. DateTime.Now.LastDayOfMonth();

Comment: I liked this approtch the best. However I noticed that it didn't actually get the end of the last day, it got 12am.
I did this instead DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1);
returns "9/30/2020 11:59:59 PM" instead of "9/30/2020 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: @Skint077 - Use AddMilliSeconds instead. Its a tiny bit more accurate

Answer (score 12):

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.AddDays(1-(date.Day)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution when you need the time part of the date to be preserved.  The other solutions don't do that. I suggest to rewrite "AddDays(1-(date.Day))" to "AddDays(-date.Day + 1)" to make the intent clearer.

Answer (score 12):

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month)
```

Answer (score -9):

try this. It will solve your problem.

```
 var lastDayOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(int.Parse(ddlyear.SelectedValue), int.Parse(ddlmonth.SelectedValue));
DateTime tLastDayMonth = Convert.ToDateTime(lastDayOfMonth.ToString() + "/" + ddlmonth.SelectedValue + "/" + ddlyear.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Constructing a `string` so you can [parse it into a `DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xhz1w05e.aspx#remarksToggle) is inefficient and reliant on the date formatting of the current culture.  There are cleaner solutions provided by the other three-year-old answers.