# Get specific dates

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am working with dates in C# and need to calculate some further dates. Taking the current `datetime`.

How can I get the following values?

- end of day
- end of month
- end of year

Comment: What do you mean _end of.._?

Comment: What do you mean by end of day? Do you mean end of business day like 5PM or 11.59 PM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by `end of ...` you mean `12:59:59.999PM` at that day then:

- end of day

  ```
  var today = DateTime.Today;
  var endOfDay = new DateTime(
      today.Year, 
      today.Month,
      today.Day,
      23,
      59,
      59,
      999
  );
  ```
- end of month

  ```
  var today = DateTime.Today;
  var endOfMonth = new DateTime(
      today.Year, 
      today.Month,
      DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month),
      23,
      59,
      59,
      999
  );
  ```
- end of year

  ```
  var today = DateTime.Today;
  var endOfYear = new DateTime(
      today.Year,
      12,
      31,
      23,
      59,
      59,
      999
  );
  ```

If you mean something else, then explain what you mean.

Comment: It should be 11:59 of course. Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For end of month

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month));
```

see [How can I get the last day of the month in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655143/how-can-i-get-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-c)

For end of year

```
DateTime endOfYear = new DateTime(today.Year, 12, 31);
```

For end of day, assuming the end of day is close of business at 5 PM

```
DateTime endOfDay = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.day, 17, 0, 0); // Assuming the business end of day is at 5 PM
```

See more about datetime at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Last day of month:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month));
```

Last day of year:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime lastDayOfYear = new DateTime(today.Year, 12, 31);
```