# Entering data with 1 statement into 12 textboxes automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a codeblock i wish to run 12 times, into different textboxes for each month.

What it does is uses row filter to match month(which i can only get working using an upper and lower range instead of month name) and count how many entries there are.

//February Example:

```
        DataView dvfeb = new DataView();
        dvfeb = DtSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        dvfeb.RowFilter = "([Actual Start Date]>= '1/02/2012' and [Actual Start Date] < '28/02/2012')";
        int febval = dvfeb.Count;
        febbox.Text = febval.ToString();
```

// March Example

```
        DataView dvmar = new DataView();
        dvmar = DtSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        dvmar.RowFilter = "([Actual Start Date]>= '1/03/2012' and [Actual Start Date] < '30/03/2012')";
        int marval = dvmar.Count;
        marbox.Text = marval.ToString();
```

How would i get it to change the feb, mar, apr dataview names and textboxes automatically? And is there an easier to use row filter so it can be included in this loop aswell?

Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using Find to find the control. try below code. assume the 12 textbox are Janbox, Febbox, Marbox, .... case insensitive (the first 3 letters of the month + box).

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, i, 1);
            DateTime endDate;
            if (i < 12)
            {
                endDate = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, i + 1, 1)).AddDays(-1);
            }
            else
            {
                endDate = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 1, 1)).AddDays(-1);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(startDate.ToString() + " " + endDate.ToString());

            DataView dv = new DataView();
            dv = DtSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            string filter = "([Actual Start Date]>= '{0}' and [Actual Start Date] < '{1}')";
            filter = string.Format(filter, startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), endDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            dv.RowFilter = filter;

            int val = dv.Count;

            string controlName = startDate.ToString("MMMM");
            controlName = controlName.Substring(0, 3).ToLower() + "box";
            Control[] cs = this.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
            if (cs != null && cs.Length > 0)
            {
                // assume the textbox exist and unique
                TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)(cs[0]);
                txtbox.Text = val.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you want the full date, why not use `DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month)`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-a-month

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure on this, but couldnt you just check the month number?

```
var monthNumber = monthMap[txtbox];
rowfilter = 'actualstartdatemonth = ' + monthNumber;
txtbox.Text = ++currentMonthCountMap[monthNumber];
```

Where your `monthMap` is a dictionary that maps the textbox to a month number, and `currentMonthCountMap` is a dictionary that stores your count;

If you want the full date then per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-a-month) you could do the following:

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, monthNumber);
```