# Trying to write my own date program, need a check for max date for specified month in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write my own Date program in C#, the problem I've having is that when the user inputs a date for example 2-31, the program allows it. I want to create a condition where I can match which month is entered and then from that see if the day is available in that month. I'm using this code below but it's throwing me the exception for any day such as October 10 which should be right. If I comment this out the date works but it won't check to match the month.

```
public int Day
    {
        get
        {
            return day;
        } 
        private set 
        {
            //int[] daysPerMonth = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 
            //                 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

            //// check if day in range for month
            //if (value > 0 && value <= daysPerMonth[Month])
            //    day = value;

            //else // day is invalid
            //    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            //       "Day", value, "Day out of range for current month/year");

            if (value > 0 && value <= 31) 
                day = value;
            else 
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", value, "Day must be 1-31");

        } 
    }
```

Comment: are you trying to do something without using the built in datetime objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to know what month the user is selecting as well as the year (to correctly handle leap years).

It would have to be something like this:

```
public int Day
{
    get
    {
        return day;
    } 
    private set 
    {
        var endOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        if (value > 0 && value <= endOfMonth.Day) 
            day = value;
        else 
        {
            var message = string.Format("Day must be between {0} and {1}", 1 endOfMonth.Day);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", value, message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Where `year` and `month` are other fields in your class. If you really want to do this without any reference to the `DateTime` class, I recommend extracting this logic out into a static class which can do the math without having to re-code it any time you want to get the last day of the month.

```
public static class DateHelper
{
    private int[] daysInMonth = new[] { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 
                                        31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
    {
        // TODO: taken from wikipedia, can be improved
        if (year % 400 == 0)
            return true;
        else if (year % 100 == 0)
            return false;
        else if (year % 4 == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool GetDaysInMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        // TODO: check for valid ranges
        var days = daysInMonth[month - 1];
        if (month == 2 && IsLeapYear(year))
            days++;
        return days;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public int Day
{
    get
    {
        return day;
    } 
    private set 
    {
        var endOfMonth = DateHelper.GetDaysInMonth(year, month);
        if (value > 0 && value <= endOfMonth) 
            day = value;
        else 
        {
            var message = string.Format("Day must be between {0} and {1}", 1 endOfMonth);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", value, message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well I've written my own Date Program, I'm not using the C#'s class. It's supposed to be very simple, and right now I'm not trying to account for leap years, is there any way to do this?

Comment: @thewrongadvice why would you try to reinvent the wheel? Proper date handling is actually very hard to do correctly. I strongly recommend you stick with the existing `DateTime` class.

Comment: if(year%4==0){its a leap year} else{its not}

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse Nope. [It's a bit more complicated than that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). Not that it can't be done, but it's totally unnecessary.

Comment: I'm just starting out self teaching myself programming and it's one of the exercises in this book I'm reading, the book doesn't have answers though, and I want to work through all these exercises to get the most benefit from this book.

Comment: thanks @p.s.w.g, i learnt something new
if year is divisible by 400 then
   is_leap_year
else if year is divisible by 100 then
   not_leap_year
else if year is divisible by 4 then
   is_leap_year
else
   not_leap_year

Comment: You might want to take a look at Jon Skeets [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/). He basically recreated all the datetime and calendar functionality by porting Joda Time (Java) to .Net. It's all way *way* more complicated than it seems at first, but you'll learn a lot by looking at how he does stuff. Not only the coding itself but structure of projects, testing and all that.

Comment: @thewrongadvice I've provided a crude solution that does this without referencing the `DateType` type. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it had to be done using ***DateTime*** it can be done using

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month);
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-a-month)

Comment: +1 Ha. I forgot that that method existed. My `.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)` trick is a throw back from SQL.