# How to turn DateTime to last day of the month?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

If I have a `DateTime` which is, for example, `2012-05-24`, what is the quickest way to convert it to a date which is the last day of that month (`2012-05-31`).

Comment: Already this question may discussed .**[ref][1]**


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-a-month

Answer (score 20):

Well you can use:

```
DateTime date = ...;
var endOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 
                              DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month));
```

Note that that will create a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Unspecified`. You should consider what `Kind` you really want. (Or use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, where you'd use a `LocalDate` instead.)

Comment: why did u use `var` type instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: @SubinJacob: It seemed clear enough, given that I'm explicitly calling `new DateTime(...)`. I'll change the one for `date` though.

Comment: I read it somewhere, thats y I asked. http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/CSharp-var

Comment: @SubinJacob: Personally, I think `TYPE variable = new TYPE(...` is needlessly redundant.  I wish the compiler supported `TYPE variable = new(...` as an alternative to var.  That would be feasible even on fields.  Of course, adding numerous pointless syntax variations for minor syntactic sugar is a bad idea, so it's just as well that my wish is ungranted.

Answer (score 9):

Here's some extension methods I use:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensionMethods
{
    public static DateTime StartOfMonth(this DateTime date)
    {
        return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    }
    public static DateTime EndOfMonth(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.StartOfMonth().AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1);
    }
}
```

Note that in my case I'm using them for SQL queries, so I want it to be up to the last second of the last day of the month.

Based on comments, yes, if you want just want the date and not time, you could use:

```
    public static DateTime EndOfMonth(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.StartOfMonth().AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    }
```

Or just use the `Date` property of the result to just get the date portion, then it satisfies both cases depending how you use it.

Comment: That "end of month" will give 11:59:59pm on the last day of the month, which isn't what was described. Admittedly the OP could then use the `Date` property, but it feels cleaner just to create a new `DateTime` at midnight, just like you do for `StartOfMonth`. (And it can be done directly very easily.)

Comment: Just change the .AddSeconds(-1) to .AddDays(-1) instead then.

Comment: @LarsJensen: At that point I'd remove my downvote, yes. It still wouldn't be my preferred solution, but it would at least be better. (It's odd to remove "one second" anyway - it's not like that represents the last `DateTime` value of the day. One *tick* would be more sensible, but usually when times are involved it's best to use an exclusive end-point for an interval anyway...)

Comment: @Timoth: Currently your SQL queries will miss out on any values which occur *within* the last second. I would change your SQL to be *exclusive* of the end point, in which case you just need the start of the next month.

Comment: @JonSkeet they are inclusive of the end point, the best solution would be to simply to make my queries < (firstOfFollowingMonth), but I can't change that part of the code, I can only feed it the start/finish dates. Given that SQL is only accurate to 1/3 of a second, there's only the potential to miss 2 data points. It was more important for my code to NOT include anything dated at 00:00 on the first of the following month, so I chose to avoid rounding issues.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-05-24");            
DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 05, 24);
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month));
```

**Output:** 5/31/2012 12:00:00 AM

You can then modify this to your required format.