# How to determine if a date is the last day of the month?

Tags: vb.net

Can somebody help me on how to determine if the given date was the last date or day in a month?

For example I have two dates, the one is 2013-01-27 and the other one is 2013-02-28. I need to determine if which date was the last day. So the one that must be display was the 2013-02-28 because its the last day of the month in february while 2013-01-27 was not the last day of the month in January.

What will be the condition that I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-a-month

Comment: This may help you                                                             Get the last day of the month
Public Function LastDayOfMonth(ByVal sourceDate As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim lastDay As DateTime = New DateTime(sourceDate.Year, sourceDate.Month, 1)
    Return lastDay.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
End Function

Comment: @VB.NETLEARNER this would be better off added as an answer rather than a comment.  For one thing it will allow you to format your code propertly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
Function IsLastDay(ByVal myDate As Date) As Boolean
    return myDate.Day = Date.DaysInMonth(myDate.Year, myDate.Month)
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Add one day and if the resulting answer is not the same month, your date is the last day of the month.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
Dim isLastDayOfMonth As Func(Of DateTime, Boolean) = _
    Function (dt) dt.AddDays(1).Day = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps you, its the code for the suggested answer of Shawn de Wet.
You can switch Datetime.today.month for another variable with a specific date, then just switch the Today.Adddays(1) with the specific date.AddDays(1)

```
Dim dateOfToday As DateTime = Today.AddDays(1)

Sub isTodayTheLastDay()
    If DateTime.Today.Month = dateOfToday.Month Then
        'yes its the same month, place code here
    Else
        'no its not the same month, place code here
    End If

End Sub
```

--

```
Dim dateToCheck As New DateTime(2013, 4, 21) 'any date you want to check here
Dim Check As DateTime = dateToCheck.AddDays(1)


Sub isTodayTheLastDay()
    If dateToCheck.Month = Check.Month Then
        'yes its the same month, place code here
    Else
        'no its not the same month, place code here
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is somewhat confusing.  Perhaps you might want to clarify it a bit further?  How does looking at today's date tell the user whether or not a separate arbitrary date is the last day of its month?

Comment: I simply used 'today' as the date to check as in "Is today the last day of the month?"
I'll edit my post and add code for any date.(like i tried to explain in the original answer) sorry for the confusion and late reply.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can check if the following day is the first day of the month.

If you are using ruby, you can use the condition:

```
(date + 1).day == 1
```

Or if you are using python:

```
(date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).day == 1
```

Cheers!

Comment: Sir how about in vb.net?

Comment: The original question is very specifically about VB.NET, so answers in Python and Ruby aren't relevant.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the tag. Sorry!