# Calculate Last Day of the Next Month

Tags: c#, datetime

I am attempting to use the DateTime function in C# to calculate the last day of next month.

For example, today is December 17th 2015.  I want the DateTime function to return January 31st 2016 (the last day of next month).

I am using the following to calculate the first day of next month (this works):

```
DateTime firstDayNextMonth = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-DateTime.Now.Day+1).AddMonths(1);
```

Comment: Add months(2).addday(-1)?

Comment: Given the astonishing number of wrong answers this question has attracted in less than ten minutes you can perhaps be forgiven for that keyboard mark on your forehead. Ignore the answers; you will spend more time trying to figure out what is wrong with each than it will take you to derive the correct answer. Go back to first principles. You have a current date. Can you work out what the month *and year* will be next month? Do so. Once you have that information, can you work out how many days that month has? Now you have the answer to your question: a year, a month, and a day.

Comment: The title says last day, variable is first day. Do you know what date you want?

Comment: OK, don't ignore Ben's answer.

Comment: @EricLippert: lol.  Anyways, this seems like the perfect case for using that ["Come Alive" plugin](https://comealive.io/) that Josh Varty showed off at MVP summit.

Comment: Most of the answer covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-a-month (which can be found using a search engine like https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+last+day+of+month )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
DateTime reference = DateTime.Now;
DateTime firstDayThisMonth = new DateTime(reference.Year, reference.Month, 1);
DateTime firstDayPlusTwoMonths = firstDayThisMonth.AddMonths(2);
DateTime lastDayNextMonth = firstDayPlusTwoMonths.AddDays(-1);
DateTime endOfLastDayNextMonth = firstDayPlusTwoMonths.AddTicks(-1);
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/AKDI52378

Comment: This answer has a nice property that many other answers lacked *other* than correctness. **It only calls `Now` once**. Remember, `Now` returns different values every time you call it. It is possible for `Now` to return a result in December 2015 once and in January 2016 a nanosecond later. Now, of course this means that the computed result will be *wrong*, because it is out of date, but at least the math will be done consistently and correctly.  And really there is no way to accurately answer a question about "two months from now" when you are a nanosecond away from the month changing.

Answer (score 2):

```
//system date or any date u want this case it is a calendar picker - 22/03/2016
DateTime today = dtpFrom.Value;

//Add a month to your date example , it now becomes - 22/04/2016
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month,today.Day).AddMonths(1);

//Get the last date off the above which is - 30
int getlastday = DateTime.DaysInMonth(endOfMonth.Year, endOfMonth.Month);

//Now set the date to the value  which will be the last day off the next month - 30/04/2016
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(endOfMonth.Year, endOfMonth.Month, getlastday);
```

Comment: Pls add some description instead of code-only answers.

Comment: Hi , i have added comments , hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int Day= DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month+1>12 ? 01 : DateTime.Now.Month+1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var lastDayInNextMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month );
```

@ Ben : `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)` will add `1` month to the current date not substract `11` months.

[image]

`DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Year` will give `2016` not `2015` refer the attached image

Comment: Doesn't work in December, goes backward 11 months instead of forward 1

Comment: (responding to edit) Indeed `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Year` will give 2016.  But your answer uses `DateTime.Now.Year`...

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month);
```

Comment: Doesn't work in December (easier to forgive if `DateTime.Now` wasn't in December today)

Comment: I modified it. Now it will work for any month. @BenVoigt