# Two same commands/functions with difference of time span (still whole year) but different result SQL

Tags: c#, sql

So basically what am i doing is first i select SUM `UPLACENO` of whole year and display it.

Then i select whole year but quarter by quarter (4x3 months) and when i sum it up, it gives me different result. I do not know why, i thought it is maybe because of date span but i think it is alright. So if you need something more, tell me but this is code that does all stuff.

Here is my first function:

```
using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT SUM(UPLACENO) FROM DOKUMENT WHERE (VRDOK = 15) AND (MAGACINID = @MagacinID) AND (DATUM BETWEEN @PocetakMeseca AND @KrajMeseca) OR (VRDOK = 13) AND (MAGACINID = @MagacinID) AND (DATUM BETWEEN @PocetakMeseca AND @KrajMeseca)", con))
                {
                    decimal[] mesecneVrednosti = new decimal[magacini.Length];

                    FbDataReader dr;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MagacinID", FbDbType.Integer);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PocetakMeseca", FbDbType.Date);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@KrajMeseca", FbDbType.Date);

                    DateTime pocetakMeseca = new DateTime(trenutnaBaza, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                    DateTime krajMeseca = new DateTime(trenutnaBaza, 1, 31, 23, 59, 59);
                    DateTime krajGodine = new DateTime(trenutnaBaza, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);

                    int i = 0;

                    while (krajMeseca < krajGodine)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@MagacinID"].Value = magacin;
                        cmd.Parameters["@PocetakMeseca"].Value = pocetakMeseca;
                        cmd.Parameters["@KrajMeseca"].Value = krajMeseca;

                        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            if (!(dr[0] is DBNull))
                            {
                                mesecneVrednosti[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[0]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                mesecneVrednosti[i] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        dr.Close();

                        pocetakMeseca = pocetakMeseca.AddMonths(1);
                        krajMeseca = krajMeseca.AddMonths(1);
                        i++;
                    }

                    currentChart.Titles.Add("Magacini");

                    for (int y = 0; y < meseci.Length; y++)
                    {
                        Series series = currentChart.Series.Add(Convert.ToString(meseci[y]));

                        series.Points.Add(Convert.ToDouble(mesecneVrednosti[y]));
                        currentChart.Series[y]["PointWidth"] = "1.8";
                    }
                }
```

And here is second one:

```
using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT SUM(UPLACENO) FROM DOKUMENT WHERE (VRDOK = 15) AND (MAGACINID = @MagacinID) AND (DATUM BETWEEN @PocetakKvartala AND @KrajKvartala) OR (VRDOK = 13) AND (MAGACINID = @MagacinID) AND (DATUM BETWEEN @PocetakKvartala AND @KrajKvartala)", con))
                {
                    decimal v_prviKvartal = 0;
                    decimal v_drugiKvartal = 0;
                    decimal v_treciKvartal = 0;
                    decimal v_cetvrtiKvartal = 0;

                    FbDataReader dr;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MagacinID", FbDbType.Integer);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PocetakKvartala", FbDbType.Date);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@KrajKvartala", FbDbType.Date);

                    DateTime pocetakKvartala = new DateTime(trenutnaBaza, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                    DateTime krajKvartala = new DateTime(trenutnaBaza, 3, 31, 23, 59, 59);
                    DateTime krajGodine = new DateTime(trenutnaBaza, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);

                    int kvartal = 1;

                    while (krajKvartala < krajGodine)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@MagacinID"].Value = magacin;
                        cmd.Parameters["@PocetakKvartala"].Value = pocetakKvartala;
                        cmd.Parameters["@KrajKvartala"].Value = krajKvartala;

                        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            if (!(dr[0] is DBNull))
                            {
                                switch(kvartal)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        v_prviKvartal = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[0]);
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        v_drugiKvartal = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[0]);
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        v_treciKvartal = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[0]);
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        v_cetvrtiKvartal = Convert.ToDecimal(dr[0]);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                prviKvartal.Text = "0";
                            }
                        }
                        dr.Close();

                        pocetakKvartala = pocetakKvartala.AddMonths(3);
                        krajKvartala = krajKvartala.AddMonths(3);

                        kvartal++;
                    }
                    decimal ukupno = v_prviKvartal + v_drugiKvartal + v_treciKvartal + v_cetvrtiKvartal;

                    prviKvartal.Text = String.Format("{0:n}", v_prviKvartal) + " - " + String.Format("{0:n}%", (v_prviKvartal / ukupno) * 100);
                    drugiKvartal.Text = String.Format("{0:n}", v_drugiKvartal) + " - " + String.Format("{0:n}%", (v_drugiKvartal / ukupno) * 100);
                    treciKvartal.Text = String.Format("{0:n}", v_treciKvartal) + " - " + String.Format("{0:n}%", (v_treciKvartal / ukupno) * 100);
                    cetvrtiKvartal.Text = String.Format("{0:n}", v_cetvrtiKvartal) + " - " + String.Format("{0:n}%", (v_cetvrtiKvartal / ukupno) * 100);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the end of the month just by using `AddMonths(1)`. It will work until *February* (giving you `28.02` or `29.02`) but after that you'll get 28th (or 29th) of *March* and so on. Thus you calculate not entire months in the first scenario while in case of quarters you accidentally do not loose days.

You can use the solution from here: [ [How do I get the last day of a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-do-i-get-the-last-day-of-a-month) ] in order to find out the request parameters

Comment: I tried with that but it is not working at all. How should my switching to next month need to look like

Comment: At the bottom of a cycle you could try either krajMeseca= new DateTime (trenutnaBaza, i+1,       DateTime.DaysInMonth(trenutnaBaza, 
                                                        i+1), 23,59,59); or simply krajMeseca = new DateTime(trenutnaBaza, 1, 31, 23, 59, 59).AddMonths (i+1); assuming i has not been incremented

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

Problem was that `DateTime.AddMonth` add `+1` to month so when february comes (28 days) and it adds one month but that is still 28th day but now of march.

I solved it like this:

`krajMeseca = new DateTime(trenutnaBaza, krajMeseca.Month + 1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(trenutnaBaza, krajMeseca.Month + 1), 23, 59, 59);`

Comment: Your solution is basically the same as the one I suggested.

Comment: @Igor yes it is, but on SO if you solved question you need to place it as answer and mark it as done. Thanks for help.

Comment: In fact if you get the answer from someone that solves your problem you mark this answer as done. You post your solution only if you have not got any good answer and solved the problem yourself.