# c# adding correct month based on previous month

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am trying to add a month to a date and populate textboxes based on the previous month. For months that end on the 31st (and even February 28th) this works. But, if the previous month ended on the 30th and the next month ends on the 31st, it is either one day short or one day long. For example:

Previous start date: 4/1/2017 
Previous end date: 4/30/2017 
New start date: 5/1/2017 
New end date: **SHOULD BE** 5/31/2017

Here is the code I have:

```
// Set the Start Date
DateTime dtNewStartDate;
dtNewStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtRecentBeginDate.Text).AddMonths(1);
txtNewStartDate.Text = dtNewStartDate.ToString();

// Set the End Date
DateTime dtNewEndDate;
dtNewEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtNewStartDate.Text).AddMonths(1);
txtNewEndDate.Text = dtNewEndDate.ToString();
```

This produces an end date of 6/1/2017 instead of 5/31/2017

**EDIT:** I was able to find what I was looking for from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/218260ec-b610-4fa6-9d1b-f56f3438b721/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-a-particular-month?forum=Vsexpressvcs.
This solution accounts for leap years and getting the correct last day of the month for any circumstance. This is what I came up with:

```
// Set the End Date
int intYear = dtNewStartDate.Year;
int intMonth = dtNewStartDate.Month;
int intNumberOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(intYear, intMonth);
DateTime dtNewEndDate = new DateTime(intYear, intMonth, intNumberOfDays);
txtNewEndDate.Text = dtNewEndDate.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you expand on "I am trying to add a month to a date and populate textboxes based on the previous month"?

Comment: Your two code examples are identical.

Comment: Exactly what finrod said. How are you getting two different outputs from the same code snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the last day of a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-do-i-get-the-last-day-of-a-month)

Answer (score 2):

You can just get the last day of the month for that month.

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
 DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, 
                               today.Month, 
                               DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, 
                                                    today.Month));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I typically do: Just take the year and month from the start date, create a new date based on that, add a month and subtract a day which ends up being the last day of the next month::

```
DateTime dtNewEndDate = new DateTime(dtNewStartDate.Year, dtNewStartDate.Month, 1)
    .AddMonths(1)
    .AddDays(-1);
```