# Getting first and last day of the current month in two input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

hello community I have two input dates start date and end date start date must be the current date and the end date must be the last day of the month how can I do this?

To get the current date and pass it in the `bind-value` I do this:

```csharp
public Precio Pre = new Precio()
{
    Fecha_Inicio = DateTime.Now,
};
```

and I put it is the input date:

```razor
<input type="date" class="form-control" @bind-value="@Pre.Fecha_Inicio" />
```

this is the other input date:

```razor
<input type="date" class="form-control" @bind-value="@Precio.Fecha_Final" />
```

this code is to put the last day of the month to the end date, but I don't know how to use it correctly:

```csharp
private async Task AddDays()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
    var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
}
```

Comment: the start and end dates must be set by default in the form, they will not be filled in by the user, but if you can see them in the form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the last day of a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-do-i-get-the-last-day-of-a-month). You would use DateTime.Now as the start date and the method mentioned here as the end date... what's not working ... can you provide details plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally create an extension method for this, as I could see reusing it elsewhere. And then calling something like this:

```
public Precio Pre = new Precio()
    {           
       Fecha_Inicio = DateTime.Now,
       Fecha_Final = Fecha_Inicio.LastDayOfMonth()
    };
```

.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime inDate)
    {
        var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(inDate.Year, inDate.Month);
        return new DateTime(inDate.Year, inDate.Month, daysInMonth);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the start_date to pass it LastDayOfMonth (), does not exist in the current context

Comment: `DateTime.Now` would be the same, you can pass that instead (ie `Fecha_Final = DateTime.Now.LastDayOfMonth()`)

Comment: I already edited it as you tell me but now DateTime.Now does not contain a definition for LastDayOfMonth

Comment: you have to include the `DateTimeExtensions` class with a `using`. Are you doing that? see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: is it a package that i have to install with nuget? because I put this @using DateTimeExtensions and it says using directive is not necessary

Comment: No, it's not a nuget package. It's an extension method. Create a new class file in your project, called 'DateTimeExtensions'. I will usually put this in a subfolder called 'helpers' or similar. Look at the namespace assigned to the file. Add the class code. In your other class (where you initialize `Precio`) add a using directive to the namespace containing the extension method. Alternatively, *don't* put it in an extension method, just put the `LastDayOfMonth` method in your class. I have to say, though, what I am suggesting is very common and straightforward. You should probably know it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, help and information about the extension methods. I was lost on how to use them, it already worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```csharp
var today = DateTime.Today;

var first = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
var second = first.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Note that this solution is quite messy, but You can add some comments or use more appropriate variable names to make it a bit better and more readable.

Also You can use this:

```csharp
var today = DateTime.Today;
int daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month);

var first = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
var last = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, daysCount);
```

Comment: but how do I pass those variables to the input bind-values for example Fecha inicio = today , fecha_final= second

Comment: You can use properties instead of variables (e.g. public DateTime LastDay = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month)))

Answer (score -1):

To get the last day of month within a specific date simply call:

```cs
DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month);
```

For August, the function will return 31.

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493032/how-do-i-get-the-last-day-of-a-month)

Comment: public Precio Pre = new Precio()
        {
            Fecha_Inicio = DateTime.Now,           
            Fecha_Final = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Fecha_Inicio.Year, Fecha_Inicio.Month);
         };won't let me set start_date as current date

Comment: Fecha_Final = new DateTime(Fecha_Inicio.Year, Fecha_Inicio.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Fecha_Inicio.Year, Fecha_Inicio.Month)); because DateTime.DaysInMonth(Fecha_Inicio.Year, Fecha_Inicio.Month) will only return the last day of the month (e.g. for month August it will return 31)!